# Group and sum list of dictionaries by parameter

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, grouping

I have a list of dictionaries of my products (drinks, food, etc), some of the products may be added several times. I need to group my products by product_id parameter and sum product_cost and product_quantity of each group to get the total product price.

I'm a newbie in python, understand how to group list of dictionaries but can't figure out how to sum some parameter values.

```
"products_list": [
    {
        "product_cost": 25,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 14,
    },
    {
        "product_cost": 176.74,
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "Apples",
        "product_quantity": 800,

    },
    {
        "product_cost": 13,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 7,
    }
]
```

I need to achieve something like that:

```
"products_list": [
    {
        "product_cost": 38,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 21,
    },
    {
        "product_cost": 176.74,
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "Apples",
        "product_quantity": 800,

    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have already tried?

Comment: Only grouping via appending to defaultdict in loop

Comment: Could you provide what you already tried, also check my answer below, I have done using the same approach as yours @NatalyFirstova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by sorting the list of dictionaries on `product_name`, and then group items based on `product_name`

Then for each group, calculate the total product and total quantity, create your final dictionary and update to the list, and then make your final dictionary

```
from itertools import groupby

dct = {"products_list": [
    {
        "product_cost": 25,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 14,
    },
    {
        "product_cost": 176.74,
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "Apples",
        "product_quantity": 800,

    },
    {
        "product_cost": 13,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 7,
    }
]}

result = {}
li = []

#Sort product list on product_name
sorted_prod_list = sorted(dct['products_list'], key=lambda x:x['product_name'])

#Group on product_name
for model, group in groupby(sorted_prod_list,key=lambda x:x['product_name']):

    grp = list(group)

    #Compute total cost and qty, make the dictionary and add to list
    total_cost = sum(item['product_cost'] for item in grp)
    total_qty = sum(item['product_quantity'] for item in grp)
    product_name = grp[0]['product_name']
    product_id = grp[0]['product_id']

    li.append({'product_name': product_name, 'product_id': product_id, 'product_cost': total_cost, 'product_quantity': total_qty})

#Make final dictionary
result['products_list'] = li

print(result)
```

The output will be

```
{
    'products_list': [{
            'product_name': 'Apples',
            'product_id': 2,
            'product_cost': 176.74,
            'product_quantity': 800
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'Coca-cola',
            'product_id': 1,
            'product_cost': 38,
            'product_quantity': 21
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with pandas:

```
d = {"products_list": [
    {
        "product_cost": 25,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 14,
    },
    {
        "product_cost": 176.74,
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_name": "Apples",
        "product_quantity": 800,

    },
    {
        "product_cost": 13,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Coca-cola",
        "product_quantity": 7,
    }
]}
```

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d["products_list"])
```

Pass dict to pandas and perform groupby.
Then convert it back to dict with to_dict function.

```
result={}
result["products_list"]=df.groupby("product_name",as_index=False).sum().to_dict(orient="records")
```

Result:

```
{'products_list': [{'product_cost': 176.74,
   'product_id': 2,
   'product_name': 'Apples',
   'product_quantity': 800},
  {'product_cost': 38.0,
   'product_id': 2,
   'product_name': 'Coca-cola',
   'product_quantity': 21}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me personally I would reorganize it in to another dictionary by unique identifiers.  Also, if you still need it in the list format you can still reorganize it in a dictionary, but you can just convert the dict.values() in to a list.  Below is a function that does that.

```
def get_totals(product_dict):
    totals = {}
    for product in product_list["product_list"]:
        if product["product_name"]  not in totals:
            totals[product["product_name"]] = product
        else:

            totals[product["product_name"]]["product_cost"] += product["product_cost"]
            totals[product["product_name"]]["product_quantity"] += product["product_quantity"]

    return list(totals.values())
```

output is:

```
[
 {
  'product_cost': 38,
  'product_id': 1,
  'product_name': 'Coca-cola', 
  'product_quantity': 21
 },
 {
  'product_cost': 176.74,
  'product_id': 2, 
  'product_name': 'Apples',
  'product_quantity': 800
 }
]
```

Now if you need it to belong to a product list key.  Just reassign the list to the same key.  Instead of returning `list(total.values())` do

```
product_dict["product_list"] = list(total.values())
return product_dict
```

The output is a dictionary like:

```
{
 "products_list": [
   {
    "product_cost": 38,
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Coca-cola",
    "product_quantity": 21,
   },
   {
    "product_cost": 176.74,
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "Apples",
    "product_quantity": 800,

   }
 ]
}
```